# ExoPlayer blocks the UI after updating the version

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, exoplayer

I'm working on an app that uses ExoPlayer to play an ad audio then an HLS live stream. Once the ad finishes playing, the live stream starts playing immediately. In the main while, the screen displays a 10 second countdown timer with a text. Everything works fine if the ExoPlayer version is 2.12.3 or lower. But after updating to a later version (2.18.2 the latest), the countdown timer stops working. When the live stream starts playing, the UI gets blocked. The screen becomes blank, the countdown timer cannot be shown. But after about 10 seconds, the screen displays the player UI. Here is my code.

```
val countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
    override fun onTick(ms: Long) {
        try {
            if (ms.toInt() / 1000 == 1)
                binding.skipText.text =
                    context?.getString(R.string.continue_automatically_one_second, (ms / 1000).toString())
            else
                if (ms / 1000 > 0)
                    binding.skipText.text =
                        context?.getString(R.string.continue_automatically, (ms / 1000).toString())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    override fun onFinish() {
        try {
            closeAdView()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}

audioServiceViewModel.playbackState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    val animation = resources.getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime)
    if (it.state == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_STOPPED)
        audioServiceViewModel.playOrPauseLiveStream()
    if (it.state == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING && audioServiceViewModel.streamType == StreamType.LIVE_STREAM) {
        binding.skipText.apply {
            alpha = 0f
            visibility = VISIBLE
            animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(animation.toLong())
                .setListener(null)
        }
        if (!countDownTimerStarted) {
            countDownTimer?.start()
            countDownTimerStarted = true
        }
    }
}

fun playOrPauseLiveStream() {
    if (isPlaying)
        pause()
    else
        playLiveStream()
}

fun playLiveStream() {
    if (shouldDisplayAd())
        playAd(result)

    val livePrefs = LiveSharedPreferences(prefs)
    var shouldContinue = true

    nowPlaying.value?.let {
        if (isPlaying) {
            livePrefs.getString(GlobalConstants.SELECTED_STREAM, "").observeForever { id ->
                shouldContinue = if (id == it.getString(MetadataKey.STREAM_ID)) {
                    transportControls.play()
                    false
                } else
                    true
            }
        }
    }

    if (shouldContinue)
        operationQueue.add {
            mediaController.sendCommand(
                MediaControllerCommand.CMD_INIT_LIVE_STREAM,
                Bundle(),
                ResultReceiver(operationsHandler)
            )
        }
}

fun playAd(ad: VastAd?) {
        operationQueue.add {
            val gson = Gson()

            val args = Bundle().apply {
                putString(MediaControllerCommand.ARG_AD_OBJECT, gson.toJson(ad))
            }

            mediaController.sendCommand(
                MediaControllerCommand.CMD_INIT_AD_STREAM, args,
                ResultReceiver(operationsHandler)
            )
        }
    }

override fun onCommand(
    player: Player,
    command: String,
    extras: Bundle?,
    cb: ResultReceiver?
): Boolean {
    when (command) {
        MediaControllerCommand.CMD_INIT_LIVE_STREAM -> {
            return prepareLiveStream(extras)
        }
        MediaControllerCommand.CMD_INIT_AD_STREAM -> {
            return prepareAdStream(extras)
        }
    }

    return false
}


fun prepareAdStream(extras: Bundle?): Boolean {
    val adUrl = “some_vast_ad_url”

    val dataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory().setUserAgent(userAgent)
    val mediaSource =
        ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse(ad)))

    exoPlayer.apply {
        playWhenReady = true
        setMediaSource(mediaSource)
        prepare()
    }

    StreamMetadata.apply {
        type = StreamType.AD_STREAM
    }

    return true
}

fun prepareLiveStream(extras: Bundle?): Boolean {
    var streamUrl = “some_stream_url”

    val dataSourceFactory =
        DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory().setUserAgent(userAgent)
    val mediaSource =
        HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(streamUrl))

    exoPlayer.apply {
        playWhenReady = true
        setMediaSource(mediaSource)
        prepare()
    }

    StreamMetadata.apply {
        type = StreamType.LIVE_STREAM
    }

    return true
}
```

I have tried to launch a CoroutineScope in the main thread like this, but it does not work.

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
    audioServiceViewModel.playOrPauseLiveStream()
}
```

Comment: Please add your complete activity code related to ExoPlayer

Comment: I have added ExoPlayer related code above.